# How to make the first value in a date column name the file name

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a column which outputs a date for every row. I want my code to scan the first row of that column to name my file with it.
E.g. If in the column called **"Date"**, the first row in that column gives this following output:

**2022-03-25 8:00:00**

I want to name my file **"Quarter 1 2022"** using that date as a reference.

So what I have is:

```
0        Date
1        2022-03-25 08:00:00
2        2022-03-25 08:00:00
3        2022-02-27 08:00:00
4        2022-01-01 08:00:00
5        2022-01-01 08:00:00
6        2022-01-01 08:00:00
```

I have come across using np.where. But I don't know how to associate the output to be read as the filename. My idea is that I use this code:

```
    df.loc[:, "Date"].iloc[1] = np.where.df.loc[:, "Date"].iloc[1] \
        <"2022-04-01", FilepathName,

FilepathName = "Quarter 1 2022"

Filepath = r'C:/Users/downloads/ ' + FilepathName.csv
```

The first line isolates the row in the **Date** column, should the date be before **2022-04-01**, then it creates a string variable called **FilepathName**. I insert this string variable into a filepath variable called **Filepath** and then finally save the dataframe as a csv into the new filepath with the new given name.

I am struggling to finish the code:

```
df.loc[:, "Date"].iloc[1] = np.where.df.loc[:, "Date"].iloc[1] \
            <"2022-04-01", FilepathName,
```

so that I am able to save **FilepathName** as a string variable.

How can I complete this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using Pandas's builtin `dt.quarter` function:

```py
import pandas as pd
#### make OP's list of dates dataframe
Date = [ "2022-03-25 08:00:00", "2022-03-25 08:00:00", "2022-02-27 08:00:00", "2022-01-01 08:00:00", "2022-01-01 08:00:00", "2022-01-01 08:00:00"]
df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":Date})

# Convert them to date time objects with the correct formatting
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y/%m/%d')

# Sort by most recent date
df = df.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)

# Get the quarter and year and combine it 
"Quarter {} {}".format(df.Date.dt.quarter[0], df.Date[0].year)
```

Output:

```
'Quarter 1 2022'
```

And then you can save it all like so:

```py
# Get the quarter and year and combine it 
FilepathName = "Quarter {} {}".format(df.Date.dt.quarter[0], df.Date[0].year)
Filepath = r'C:/Users/downloads/' + FilepathName + ".csv"

df.to_csv(Filepath, index=False)
```

Comment: The last line which produces "Quarter 1 2022" is giving me errors since I am using my own dataframe imported from a csv. So when I read I tried using: 
{"Quarter " + str(df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"].iloc[1].dt.quarter[0]) + " " + str(df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"].iloc[1].year) }
and it gave me this error:
{AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'}
I do apologise if this is a dumb question but how would I tailor my code to work like yours? I am quite new to coding you see.

Comment: Did you convert the column to datetime ? `df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y/%m/%d')`

Comment: To tailor my code to yours, try removing the `.dt` and just have `str(df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"].iloc[1].quarter)`

Comment: Yes I had already converted the column into datetime64[ns] before creating this question.
df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"], errors='coerce')

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Now I would save that output as a string variable.

Comment: See [mmustafaicer's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469184/mmustafaicer) answer as well. Both work nicely where his uses the Timestamp format and mine is Datetime

Comment: I am tailoring my code to try his as well but getting 
^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.Timestamp()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)

try this:

```py
FilepathName = 'Quarter {} {}'.format(pd.Timestamp(df['Date'][0]).quarter, pd.Timestamp(df['Date'][0]).year)
```

Output:

```
'Quarter 1 2022'
```

Comment: Your string formatting is much cleaner than mine, I'm updating my answer to use this.

Comment: using `print('Quarter {} {}'.format(pd.Timestamp(df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"].iloc[1].quarter), pd.Timestamp(df.loc[:, "Survey.Sent.Date"].iloc[1].year)))`
seems to produce:
`Quarter 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000002022`

Comment: Because, `pd.Timestamp` accepts value to as its first argument. By using `iloc` you are either appending `DataFrame` object or `Series` there. My suggestion is to use bracket accessor for column and row indexing to access to first row such as `df['Date'][0]`

Comment: changing the headers using your suggested code now puts the first row as data without column headers. So I can't select "Survey.Sent.Data" anymore I get key error. Whilst your method is probably the preferred one, I'm afraid I'm much too inexperienced to reformat my dataframe to suit your code it seems.

Comment: @Scythor I could be wrong though. If you can see column names by running `df.columns`, then you don't have to change headers. I think problem here now is about accessors. The code I posted worked on my notebook and gave the desired output. You need to work on accessors. `df['column_name'][index_of_row]` it should be in this format. I hope this last one helps.